# Space between UICollectionViewCell rows

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, ios7

Currently I have a 9 items displayed in my collection. I want a 3*3 grid for each section I have. So when I want to go to the next section I scroll to the right and and I see the 3*3 grid for my next section. What I did to accomplish this was setting the height of the UICollection to 3*height_of_my_cell. I also made sure that:

```
- (CGFloat)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout minimumLineSpacingForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 0.0f;
}

- (CGFloat)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 0.0f;
}

- (UIEdgeInsets)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout insetForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section {
    return UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
```

So the goal is really to have the cells pasted to each other (no space between them). The problem is that what I am getting is this:
[image]

To see the 7,8 and 9 I need to scroll to the right. So I see that I am able to get rid of the space between the "columns" but not the rows. So do I need o create a custom `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` to achieve this? Also this is being done on iOS7, which I am not sure if it might influence the final result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Was able to solve the issue, by creating a custom `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` and adding this line:

```
[self setSectionInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(-65.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f)];
```

[image]

Answer (score 8):

Just set the property of `UICollectionViewFlowLayout`, such as:

> UICollectionViewFlowLayout *layout=[[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];
>    layout.minimumLineSpacing = 0;