# UICollectionViewFlowLayout: how does sectionInset work?

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

I am struggling to understand how `sectionInset` works for `UICollectionViewFlowLayout`.
I made a very basic example (using the WWDC2012 example: 205 - PinchIt).

I did:

```
layout.scrollDirection = UICollectionViewScrollDirectionHorizontal;    
layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(120, 0, 0, 0);
```

and added a red line at height 120 just for reference. Here is what I get:

[image]

Why is it not adding another row of cells at the bottom?

UPDATE: just to clarify, everything is "fine" when I set the top inset to a low number, for instance 10:

```
layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(10, 0, 0, 0);
```

[image]

Comment: How many sections you have?

Comment: Couple of questions: is this on iOS7? Is the `UICollectionView`'s frame with the same size as your `UIViewController`'s `UIView`

Comment: @AnilVarghese Only 1.

Comment: @JackyBoy Yes, iOS7. And yes, the collectionView's size is the same as the controller's view. I added another picture to illustrate this.

Comment: I think I added the same issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18818099/space-between-uicollectionviewcell-rows

Comment: @JackyBoy Thanks. I don't believe it is the same thing though - as you can see in my code, I did set the sectionInset (my layout is indeed a subclass of UICollectionViewFlowLayout). Somehow, there is an artificial bottom inset even when it is set to 0 in the code.

Comment: thanks for the pictures!